# Ruby on rails using URI method to call node.js api unable to get response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app and trying to hit the node.js api through the http uri method this is my ruby controller code

```
begin
      uri = URI('http://node_api_url')
      req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
      req.body = {param1: 'data1', param2: 'data2'}.to_json
      res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
        http.request(req)

      end
      p req
      p res.body
      if res.body.blank?

        @message = 'error'
      else
        @message = 'success'
      end
    rescue
      @message = 'error'
    end
```

now when i try to hit the api whether the response from the api is a success or the error i am getting the same response in the rails console 
the output of `p res` and `p res.body` is `#<Net::HTTP::Post POST>` and
`""`  respectively in either case if there is a success or error in the api .
how can i know what is the response from the api ?

Answer (score 0):

you just try this..look like

```
require 'net/http'

def create_agent
    uri = URI('http://api.github.com')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
    req.body = {name: 'John Doe', role: 'agent'}.to_json
    res = http.request(req)
    puts "response #{res.body}"
rescue => e
    puts "failed #{e}"
end
```

Otherwise use this simple line

```
require 'httparty'
HTTParty.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users", body: {user: {email: 'user1@example.com', password: 'secret'}}).body
```

Comment: I actually wanted to hit the http post request and pass the parameters in the json format

Comment: ok fine...you just change it. req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})